# Issue on Running JUnit Selenium tests in Jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, jenkins

I'm beginner by using Selenium and Jenkins. So here is my problem.

I got on a Linux VM, jenkins which is installed and got plugins : JUnit attachment and filesystem_SCM.

I got in a folder of that VM the java files containing my selenium tests.

I would to execute from jenkins those scripts executing on a windows machine where Selenium RC is turning on.

How could I do that ? I've seen Selenium grid plugin or just tried to create a job with a shell command containing mvn instruction but I don't really understand what to do ? Does someone could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you'll want to do is to configure a Windows Machine (VMs are terrific for this) as a Selenium Slave machine and then have your tests executed there. In this scenario, your Jenkins Master (the linux VM) would trigger the slave (the windows VM) to execute the build.

In Jenkins you can do this by having the Slave execute your build that runs the tests via JUnit. You can either configure executing the tests as a separate build in Jenkins, or simply as a build step in your main build.

Here's some relevant Links:

- [Jenkins Distributed Builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds)
- [Setting up Master and Slave Machines in Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines)